Access an element of an array of struct of another contract from current contract
I have a contract Bidding.sol:
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

struct Bid {
        uint bidId;
        address initiator;
        uint chemicalId;
        uint price;
        BidStatus status;
        address topBidder;
        uint topOffer;
    }

mapping(uint => Bid) public chemicalBids;
mapping(uint => Bid) public logisticsBids;

// Utility function to get details of a specific bid
    function getBidDetails(
        uint _bidId,
        bool isChemical
    )
        public
        view
        returns (
            address initiator,
            uint chemicalId,
            uint price,
            BidStatus status,
            address topBidder,
            uint topOffer
        )
    {
        Bid memory bid = isChemical
            ? chemicalBids[_bidId]
            : logisticsBids[_bidId];
        return (
            bid.initiator,
            bid.chemicalId,
            bid.price,
            bid.status,
            bid.topBidder,
            bid.topOffer
        );
    }

I have another contract Logistics.sol:
modifier validLogisticsBid(uint _logisticsBidId) {
        (, , , , Bidding.BidStatus status, , ) = biddingContract.logisticsBids(
            _logisticsBidId
        );

        require(
            status == Bidding.BidStatus.Closed,
            "Logistics bid is not closed"
        );
        _;
    }

I want to know if there is a better way to access the members of this structure instead of doing this:
(, , , , Bidding.BidStatus status, , ) = biddingContract.logisticsBids(
            _logisticsBidId
        );

I tried these two things, both gave same error:
Bidding.Bid memory bid = biddingContract.getBidDetails(_logisticsBidId, false);
Bidding.Bid memory bid = biddingContract.logisticsBids(_logisticsBidId);
Error: Different number of components on LHS(1) than on RHS(6)


You just have to unpack the members of struct in the form of tuple, like the way you're currently doing:
(, , , , Bidding.BidStatus status, , ) = biddingContract.logisticsBids(_logisticsBidId);

So, there isn't any better way to do this currently, if you're retrieving it via mapping.
But, if you define a getter function that returns the value (i.e., the instance of struct) from that mapping, inside the Bidding contract of your Bidding.sol, like:
function getLogicsBid(uint256 _logisticsBidId) public view returns (Bid memory) {
     return logisticsBids(_logisticsBidId);
}

Then, you can directly retrieve the instance of struct by calling the getLogicsBid() function inside Logistics.sol, like:
Bidding.Bid memory bid = biddingContract.getLogicsBid(_logisticsBidId);

For more details, you can refer to this answer given by @Rob Hitchens.
